# OCaml equivalent of Python DictReader

Tags: python, csv, ocaml

I am aware of the existence of the `Csv` package in OCaml, but as far as I know, it does not enable me to load a csv file like a stream of dictionares (as `DictReader` allows me to do it in Python).

Is there a way to read such files as a stream of dictionaries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams in Python are Python's way of abstract iteration. On the other hand they are just objects that have a `__next__` method. The `Csv` module you mention provides a value `next` which behaves in exactly the same way. Furthermore the module defines some more concrete iterators like `fold_left` and `iter`. Thus it is already easy to iterate over `csv` lines (as `string list`) and to wrap an `Csv.in_channel` into an object with much the same signature and behaviour as a Python stream of `csv` lines.

It remains to convert such lines into dictionaries. Which is just a matter of mapping a line-to-dictionary converter to the iterator or stream.

Comment: Streams also let Python not have to slurp the file to memory (difficult if it's huge), does `Csv` also handle file buffering and streaming only small chunks of data upon request?

Comment: From the difference in the documentation of `Csv.fold_left` and `Csv.fold_right` I would assume that the answer is yes.

Comment: @kne, Thank you, indeed, I should have looked at the source!